Implication and Disjunction Classical Propositional Logic Proof
example : (p → q ∨ r) → ((p → q) ∨ (p → r)) :=
  (fun h₁:(p → q ∨ r) =>
     Or.elim (em p)
      (fun h₂:p =>
          Or.elim (h₁ h₂)
            (fun h₃:q => Or.inl (fun h₂ => h₃))
            (fun h₃:r => Or.inr (fun h₂ => h₃)))
      (fun h₂:¬p => sorry))

This example is from the "Theorem Proving in Lean" manual as a practice problem.  I found all the constructive proofs easy, but starting with this one, the classical proofs are much more difficult.  I think I'm on the right track, but I'm completely stumped on the "not p" implication.  Can someone give me a hint?

Look at the context and say what the goal statement is in plan English. Hint: if you pick a constructor and apply it, you get to choose between the smaller goals of "if you already had a p, could you produce a q?" and "if you already had a p, could you produce an r?"
